# c++ variable array reservation problem

Tags: c++, arrays, variables

I have a problem caused when reserving array. The problem is a heap error. The software i am making is like that:

I am making a small software to render a model of a specific format. the model contains several groups and every group contains array vertices and array of indices for these verts "such as a motorcycle model of 3 groups: front wheel, back wheel and body. After i load the model into memory, i want to render it as a vbo but the model is made of several groups as mentioned. so i am merging all the verts in all groups into one array of verts and the same goes for indices. when merging a heap error occurs when reserving the array. The code is like this:

```
    int index=0;
    for(int i=0;i<this->groupsSize;i++)
        index+=this->groups[i]->capacity.vertsSize;
    mdl_vert *m_pVertices=new mdl_vert[index];
    index=0;
    for(int i=0;i<this->groupsSize;i++)
        index+=this->groups[i]->capacity.indicesSize;
    unsigned int *m_pIndices=new unsigned int[index];
    index=0;
    for(int i=0;i<this->groupsSize;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<this->groups[i]->capacity.vertsSize;j++)
        {
            m_pVertices[index]=this->groups[i]->verts[j];
            index++;
        }
    }
```

When i reserve indices the heap error is occuring. I also used std::vector but the same error occur. can anybody give me a hint of what am i doing wrong in this case.

N.B. mdl_vert is a struct that consists of float x,y,z;caused when reserving array.

Comment: How many vertices do you have? I agree with vissi, probably overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't supply enough info to pintpoint the problem, or even what the problem is.

But there are things you can do to clean up the code, and maybe that will help.

---

#### 1. Use std::vector instead of `new`-ing raw arrays

Instead of

```
unsigned int *m_pIndices=new unsigned int[index];
```

use

```
std::vector<unsigned> indices( index );
```

Note that this `std::vector` is not itself dynamically allocated.

It uses dynamic allocation inside, and it does that correctly for you.

Even better, just use …

```
std::vector<int> indices( index );
```

… because unsigned arithmetic can easily screw up.

#### 2. Don't use misleading naming

The `m_` prefix makes it seem as if you really want to access data members, not local variables.

But you are defining local variables.

Either use the data members, or drop the `m_` name prefixes.

#### 3. Don't "reuse" variables

You're using the variable `index` for multiple successive purposes.

Declare and use one (properly named) variable for each purpose.

#### 4. Don't rely on side-effects from earlier code.

For example, you are relying on the value of `index` after a `for`-loop where it's used a loop counter.

Instead, directly use the value that you have deduced that it will have.

#### 5. Don't obscure the code with do-nothing things.

This is just a style issue, but consider removing all the `this->` qualifications. It's verbose and obscures the code; it makes the code less readable and less clear. Yes, with primitive tools like Visual Studio such qualifications can help with getting names in drop-down lists, but that's a disservice: it makes it more difficult to remember things, and without remembering things you can't have the understanding needed to write correct code.

---

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: The problem is solved, it was something that was doing an overflow before entering the function responsible for merging. it is solved now and thanks for the advices.

Answer (score 1):

How big is the resulting index? Probably just overflow occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what the error is? If not, you may want to try putting the code into a try/catch with std::exception. Generally when I have gotten errors along those lines, it was related to a st9bad_alloc error. Which essentially means the size supplied to the new was invalid or too big (either in terms or actual memory, or because of limits imposed by the system with regards to stack space). If so, validate the numbers supplied to new, and ensure the stack size is large enough (try the 'limit' command if using Linux). Good luck

Answer (score 0):

One or more of your capacity.indicesSize is likely uninitialized, so you get a way too large number. Print index before allocating